# Is there a way to change the location of the tree view in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I was wondering if there's a way to set your tree view/project to the current directory that you've navigated to via the integrated terminal.

Currently, my experience is that I can navigate to a new directory via the integrated terminal, and when I want to start editing in that new location I just type in `code .` to open an editor there. However, that opens an entirely new instance of VS code, when in reality all I'm trying to do is change the 'location' of the current editor.

Hopefully my question makes sense - let me know if it needs further clarification and I'll be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add **-r** flag to your command which will reuse existing window:

```
code . -r
```